# initiating class as a member of struct

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class with a struct member inside:

.h file:

```
class A
{
 public:

 struct Result 
 {
  int x;
  UGraph G;       <------ class definition
 };
 Result m_tempStructResult;

 A:A(void);
 void function();
}
```

.cpp file

```
A::A()
{

}

void A::function()
{
 UGraph Graph(10);      <---- object has to receive a value

 ...
              //manipulations on Graph
 ...

 m_tempStructResult.G = Graph;
}
```

the compilation error I get is:

```
error C2512: 'A::Result' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

so the problem I guess is lack of default constructor, so I added this:

```
struct Result
    {
        Result::Result(int graph_size=0) : G(graph_size){
        }

        int x;
        UGraph G;
    };
```

and the problem solved.

my question is if there is another way to initiate the class UGraph G inside the constructor of class A? and not inside its member struct?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use an initializer list in the constructor of `Result`:

```
Result::Result() : G(0)  // you have to insert some integer here
{

}
```

Another way in C++11 is to give it a default value inside the class:

```
struct Result
{
    UGraph G = UGraph(10);
};
```

For a small demonstration, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e53d23a7a768abe4).

---

**EDIT** Thanks to @OthmanBenchekroun, I finally believe I understood the question:

So here is another example code, which uses [*aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) in order to initialize the members of `Result` (without changing the constructor of the latter).

```
struct G
{
    G(int) {}
};

struct Result
{
    int x;
    G g;  
};

struct A
{
    A() : m_tempStructResult{1, G(1)} {}

    Result m_tempStructResult;
};

int main()
{
    A{};
}
```

Another Demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4269c9a921085b1).

This does not mean, however, that I would suggest to do this. Rather I would give `Result` an appropriate default constructor. Otherwise, it might become unusable.

Comment: `G` is not a member of `A`

Comment: the problem is that G is member of struct "Result" ans "Result" is a member of class A

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: correct, `G` is a member of `Result`, I made an edit. Still, the idea should have become clear :-)

Comment: @davidhigh Sorry, but I feel like you didn't read his question, he asking for a initialisation in the constructor of 'A'. He already did a initializer list in the struct result

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: ok, I got your point and it's valid. I'll make another edit.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is if there is another way to initiate the class UGraph G
>   inside the constructor of class A? and not inside its member struct?

You cannot initiate G which a member of Result without 'constructing' Result, `G` is a member of `Result` not a member of `A`. 
So the normal way to do it is initiating `Result` in the `constructor` of `A`, and the `constructor` of `Result` will initiate `G`

Comment: while this is the recommended way imo, there is still an alternative ... see my edit which you triggered (thanks again).

Comment: @davidhigh I saw it, that still initiate m_tempStructResult.G inside the constructor of Result, you just gived the constructor a copy. But that seems to be what he needed. (you're welcome)

Answer (score 1):

You can use list initialization to construct `m_tempStructResult` with specifically constructed `G` in the member initialization list of `A` (or brace-or-equal initializer of `A::m_tempStructResult`):

```
A::A():
    m_tempStructResult {
        0, // x
        10 // G, braces can be elided (only for non-explicit constructors as pointed out by davidhigh)
    }
```

`G` is still initialized in the member object, but the code is in the constructor of `A` (not the body, but the member initialization list), which I assume you meant.

Comment: As a side remark, the conversion you imply works only for non-`explicit` constructors.